# How to check if a form has been submitted when there is no submit button

Tags: ajax, forms, input

So i am using ajax request to submit a form through a link. However, when I want to receive inputs in my php, I don't know how to do so. For instance, I normally do this

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST&&isset($_REQUEST["register"]))
  {
    //do stuf here
  }
```

But now when the ajax has submitted the code, how can I check form submission. I don't even have the register (input type submit). Whenever, I do so the error message shows `No such index'' for form inputs that are inside there.

Comment: Please show your code for 'ajax request to submit a form'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you can always check if the current request is an AJAX:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest')
{
    // This is an AJAX request, proccess the data from $_POST, $_GET or $_REQUEST
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this. What if I have more than one ajax request?. This is  to say that if I have multiple forms on the same page that I want to submit using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can define the type of the `AJAX` request (`POST` or `GET`). If it is set to `POST` and has the appropriate parameter (`register`) then your PHP code should work.

Comment: but I don't have the register button. All i am doing is clicking a link. The link submits the form. But after that I need the form inputs to update my datababase

Comment: Then attach the parameter to the link - or add the required parameter as hidden field to your form.

Comment: If the form inputs aren't sent to your server, then your "link" does not what you think it should do (sending AJAX request). In that case you should show that code too.